# Web Browser close button javascript

Tags: browser

Working on web application and need to write some code in a web-browser close button, how can we do that in Javascript.

for Chrome, IE, and FireFox.

Just wants to override Close button code

Comment: do you want to close the web browser with javascript ? or do you want to override the web browser close button ?

Comment: Please look at [ask], then clarify your intent accordingly. As it stands, it's unclear what you're asking, so your question may be put on hold.

Comment: want to override the web browser close button